# Типизируем значения массива

Tags: typescript

Коллеги привет.

Есть такой тип

```
type SuperPuperType = {
  v1: number
  v2: string
}
```

И есть массив объектов состоящих из двух полей:

1. name (в котором может быть 'v1' или 'v2')
2. value в котором хочется или number или string в зависимости от того, какое значение у name.

Вот с дженериком для этого массива возникли проблемы. Подскажите плиз. Спасибо!

**UPD**
Видимо, не до конца понятно объяснил.

Вот такое должно проходить

```
const SuperArray: SuperPuperGeneric<SuperPuperType>[] = [{
  name: 'v1'
  value: 1
},{
  name: 'v2'
  value: 'fooBoo'
}]
```

А вот такие варианты нет

```
const SuperArray: SuperPuperGeneric<SuperPuperType>[] = [{
  name: 'v1'
  value: 1
},{
  name: 'v2'
  value: 2
}]

const SuperArray2: SuperPuperGeneric<SuperPuperType>[] = [{
  name: 'v3'
  value: 1
},{
  name: 'v2'
  value: 'fooBoo'
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант как у EzioMercer, но тип создаётся автоматически:

```
// Задаём мапинг { [значение name]: тип value }
type MyMapping = {
  v1: number
  v2: string
};

// Создаём юнион объектов из мапинга
type MyObject<Mapping> = keyof Mapping extends infer Key
  ? Key extends keyof Mapping
    ? {
      name: Key,
      value: Mapping[Key]
    }
    : never
  : never;

//OK
const test1: MyObject<MyMapping>[] = [{
  name: 'v1',
  value: 1
},{
  name: 'v2',
  value: 'fooBoo'
}];

//Error 1
const test2: MyObject<MyMapping>[] = [{
  name: 'v1',
  value: 1
},{
  name: 'v2',
  value: 2
}];

//Error 2
const test3: MyObject<MyMapping>[] = [{
  name: 'v3',
  value: 1
},{
  name: 'v2',
  value: 'fooBoo'
}];
```

### Как это работает?

1. Сначала мы берём юнион всех ключей типа `MyMapping` и выделяем его в параметр `Key`, он нужен чтобы можно было преобразовывать этот тип далее.
2. Проходим по всем элементам юниона и преобразовываем их в объекты. Здесь используется свойство условных типов распределяться по юниону, то есть `T<A | B>` будет вычислено как `T<A> | T<B>`. Подробнее об этом можно прочитать в [документации](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Внутри `extends` тип `Key` соответствует каждому отдельному элементу юниона.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```js
type SuperPuperType = {
  v1: number
  v2: string
}

type OneOfArray<T extends keyof SuperPuperType> = {
    name: SuperPuperType[T]
    value: SuperPuperType[T]
}

// массив из объектов OneOfArray, параметр которого принимает один из полей SuperPuperType'а
const a: OneOfArray<"v1">[] = [{
    name: 2,
    value: 2 // если сюда вставить строку, то будет ошибка
}]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Проапдейтил вопрос, не до конца понятно сформулировал. Прошу прощения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```ts
type SuperPuperType = {
    name: 'v1',
    value: number
} | {
    name: 'v2',
    value: string
};

//OK
const SuperArray: SuperPuperType[] = [{
  name: 'v1',
  value: 1
},{
  name: 'v2',
  value: 'fooBoo'
}]

//Error 1
const SuperArray1: SuperPuperType[] = [{
  name: 'v1',
  value: 1
},{
  name: 'v2',
  value: 2
}]

//Error 2
const SuperArray2: SuperPuperType[] = [{
  name: 'v3',
  value: 1
},{
  name: 'v2',
  value: 'fooBoo'
}]
```

Errors:

1. > Type '{ name: "v2"; value: number; }' is not assignable to type 'SuperPuperType'.
   >
   > Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
   >
   > Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
2. > Type '"v3"' is not assignable to type '"v1" | "v2"'.